# Reactivity Towards Electrophilic Substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

How do you decided which compound is the most or less reactive towards electrophilic substitution? For example, if the compounds are benzene, ethyl benzene, 2-phenylpropane and 2-methyl-2-phenylpropane?

[image: Compounds]

Most reactive towards electrophilic substitution means that the compound itself needs to be an electrophile (so that they don't combine), this means there needs to be a +I effect, right? But +I effect increases with an increase in the number of alkyl groups, so that would indicate that 2-methyl-2-phenylpropane would be the most reactive, but benzene is the answer for the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: You misunderstood question or there's a mistake. Steric effect is also important but not that much

Comment: Then how would I go about answering the question? Which factors are considered first?

Comment: see [this earlier answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26563/order-of-electrophilic-substitution/26569#26569)